# Calling Stored Procedure using db link from different schema

Tags: oracle, database-connection

We have oracle database and created a db link in one schema "Owner". We also have a stored procedure which is using this db link to connect to remote procedure. 
When calling this stored procedure with "Owner" credentials, it is working fine.

However, when we try to execute using "USER" credentials, it is not working. Throwing this error:
ORA-02049: timeout: distributed transaction waiting for lock

Thanks,

Comment: Have you checked the AUTHID ..

Comment: have you contacted your dba?  distributed transaction waiting for lock sounds like a dba issue.  S/he can check the v$session table (or some other way) and look for 'blocking_session is not null'